# Let $X = \{f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \{1, 0 \} $ such that $f$ is a function $\}$. Give a bijection between $X$ and $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

As stated given that $X = \{f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \{1, 0 \} $ such that $f$ is a function $\}$. What would be a bijection between $X$ and $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$?
I've seen examples that define $g(x) = \emptyset$ if $f(1)=0$ and $g(x)= \mathbb{N}$ if $f(1)=1$ but I'm still unsure of how to go about defining a bijective function given this conditions.

Comment: Well if, say, A is a subset of the natural numbers, how would $f(A)$ look like? And given two distinct subsets of the natural numbers, are their images the same or different?

Answer (score 0):

So $g:X \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$. To show $g$ is a bijection prove that

1. $g$ is a function
2. $g$ is one-to-one
3. $g$ is onto

Do you know what these 3 are? Can you finish the problem now?

Answer (score 0):

More generally, if $A$ is a set and $2^A$ represents the collection of all functions from $A$ to $\{0,1\}$, then $\mathcal{P}(A)$ and $2^A$ are bijective. To see why, for any $S \subseteq A$ define $\chi_S \in 2^A$ by
$$\chi_S(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \textrm{if } x \in S \\
0 & \textrm{if } x \in A \setminus S \end{cases}$$
then, the desired bijection is $S \mapsto \chi_S$.